# Asynchronous States Acting Odd

Tags: c#, asynchronous, client, chat

I'm attempting to create an asynchronous server/client chat program.  While I've got a lot of it down I'm hitting a roadblock.  When a client sends a packet to the server it is read just fine and further is echoed back to that client with no issues.  If another client is connected, it will EVENTUALLY receive the packet...but it may take several send calls.  Another issue is the StateObject buffer (at least thats what I think it is) isn't being cleared despite my best efforts.  So the resulted output is very erratic and odd.  Any direction would be very helpful!

Server.cs

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Async_Server
{
// State object for reading client data asynchronously
public class StateObject
{
    // Client  socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class StatesHandler
{
    public List<StateObject> States = new List<StateObject>();
    public int Counter = 0;
}

public class AsynchronousSocketListener
{
    public static Async_Server.StatesHandler stateshandler = new StatesHandler();
    // Thread signal.
    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public AsynchronousSocketListener()
    {
    }

    public static void StartListening()
    {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        // The DNS name of the computer
        // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
        //IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        //IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        //IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostByName(Dns.GetHostName());
        //IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        //IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 3000);
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Loopback;
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 3000);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection @ " + ipAddress.ToString());

            while (true)
            {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
                allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.

                listener.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener);

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();

    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.
        allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();

        //Store state instance in stateshandler
        stateshandler.States.Add(state);
        stateshandler.Counter++;

        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        listener.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener);
        Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from: " + handler.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
    }

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            String content = String.Empty;

            // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            if ((StateObject)ar.AsyncState != null)
            {
                StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket handler = state.workSocket;

                // Read data from the client socket.
                int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                    state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                        state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                    // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read
                    // more data.
                    content = state.sb.ToString();
                    if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                    {
                        // All the data has been read from the
                        // client. Display it on the console.
                        Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
                            content.Length, content);
                        // Echo the data back to the client.
                        Send(ar, content);
                        content = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Not all data received. Get more.
                        try
                        {
                            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e);
                            Console.Read();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("RAWR");
                    Console.Read();
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection terminated from: ", e);

        }

    }

    private static void Send(IAsyncResult ar, String data)
    {
        /*
        for (int i = 0; i < stateshandler.Counter; i++)
        {
            StateObject state = stateshandler.States[i];
            Socket handler = state.workSocket;
            // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
            handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), state);
        }
         */
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);


        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), state);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = state.workSocket;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }


    public static int Main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            StartListening();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }
        Console.Read();
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

Client.cs

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

public class StateObject
{
// Client socket.
public Socket workSocket = null;
// Size of receive buffer.
public const int BufferSize = 256;
// Receive buffer.
public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
// Received data string.
public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class Program
{
public static ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
public static ManualResetEvent sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
public static ManualResetEvent receiveDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public static void Connect(EndPoint remoteEP, Socket client)
{
    client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
        new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);

    connectDone.WaitOne();
}
private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete the connection.
        client.EndConnect(ar);

        Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
            client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

        // Signal that the connection has been made.
        connectDone.Set();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
private static void Send(Socket client, String data)
{
    // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
    byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

    // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
    client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None,
        new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
}
private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
        int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

        // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
        sendDone.Set();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
private static void Receive(Socket client)
{
    try
    {
        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = client;

        // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
        client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the state object and the client socket
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.workSocket;
        // Read data from the remote device.
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
            Console.WriteLine(state.sb.ToString());
            //  Get the rest of the data.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        else
        {
            // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
            if (state.sb.Length > 1)
            {
                string response = state.sb.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(response);
            }
            // Signal that all bytes have been received.
            receiveDone.Set();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 3000);
    Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    Connect(localEndPoint, sock);
    string packet;
    while (true)
    {
        packet = Console.ReadLine();
        packet += "<EOF>";
        Send(sock, packet);
        Receive(sock);
        connectDone.WaitOne();
        packet = null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: For clarification I was using the commented block of code in the Send method

Comment: nevermind I got it working.  feel free to post if any1 is interested as to how